# How can I insert a tag into a input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code and it is almost complete. If you type something and a "," in input box it will add a tag.

I just need to insert/add those tags in input box, not before the input box.

Somehow I managed to insert/add those tags in a div before the input box.

What should I use instead of this code **div.insertBefore(tag.element, maininput);**.

Here is the main code

```js
var i;

var tags=[];

var close=document.getElementsByClassName("close");

for(i=0; i<close.length; i++){

close[i].onclick=function(){

this.parentElement.style.display="none";

}

}

var div=document.createElement("DIV");

document.body.appendChild(div);

div.className="tags-input";

var maininput=document.createElement("INPUT");

var hiddeninput=document.createElement("INPUT");

div.appendChild(maininput);

maininput.setAttribute("type", "text");

maininput.setAttribute("class", "main-input");

div.appendChild(hiddeninput);

hiddeninput.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

hiddeninput.setAttribute("class", "tags-input");

maininput.addEventListener("input", function(t){

var enteredTags=maininput.value.split(",");

if(enteredTags.length>1){

maininput.value="";

enteredTags.forEach(function(t){

var filter=filterTag(t);

if(filter.length>0){

addTag(filter);

}

});

}

});

addTag("HTML");

function addTag(text){

var tag={

text: text,

element: document.createElement("SPAN")

};

tag.element.className="tag";

tag.element.textContent=text;

var span2=document.createElement("SPAN");

span2.className="close";

var cl=tag.element.appendChild(span2);

tags.push(tag);

span2.addEventListener("click", function(){

this.parentElement.style.display="none";

removeTag();

});

div.insertBefore(tag.element, maininput);

refreshTag()

}

function removeTag(){

tags.splice(tags.indexOf(tags), 1);

refreshTag()

}

function refreshTag(){

var taglist=[];

tags.forEach(function(t){

taglist.push(t.text);

});

hiddeninput.value=taglist.join(",");

}

function filterTag(tag){

return tag.replace(/[^\w -]/g, "").trim().replace(/\W+/g, "-");

}
```

```css
.tag{
     padding:4px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:20px;
  background:#ddd;
  color:black;
  margin-right:10px;
  user-select:none;
 }
 
.tag:hover{
           background:#2196f3;
     color:white; 
    }
   
.close::after{
          content:"x";
          position:absolute;
          padding:3.5px;
    margin-top:-4px;
          cursor:pointer;
    user-select:none;
    margin-left:2px;
          }
  
.close:hover::after{
             color:gray; 
             }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can't insert styled html-elements inside <input type="text"/>. What you are looking for I think, is a way to make it look like that is the case like some libraries do. That is just css to remove the border from the input and draw it outside the inserted tags also and so on.

Comment: An input box cannot contain anything other than a text. What you see in e.g. Gmail is elements being overlaid atop the input element, and input element getting padding to accommodate for the overlay. It is tricky to do correctly, and I'd suggest you take a look at how existing libraries do it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments but I want no plugins.

Comment: You don't need plugins. It can trivially be done with JavaScript, HTML and CSS. But you can't do it with an `input` element, it's a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element).

Comment: @amn - How to do that?